# Não pedir credenciais se usuário não estiver autenticado

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho um sistema com dois sites no mesmo domínio. Os dois sites ficam em pastas separadas do mesmo domínio, mais ou menos assim:

```
http://renan/foo
http://renan/bar
```

O primeiro site (vamos chamá-lo de "`foo`") tem uma página que acessa dados do outro site ("`bar`") via Ajax. Quando o usuário está logado em ambos, tudo ocorre como desejo. Mas quando o usuário está logado apenas em `foo`, o navegador mostra um prompt pedindo nome de usuário e senha. A autenticação é feita via Active Directory e nem todos os usuários de cada site devem ter acesso ao outro.

Eu gostaria que, no caso do usuário estar logado em `foo` nas não em `bar`, o prompt de login não aparecesse. Queria tratar como erro mesmo. Existe alguma forma de verificar que o sistema pediria autenticação e impedir que o prompt apareça?

Segue um snippet do código que estou usando pra requisição:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://renan/bar/baz",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Só pra clarificar: esse prompt de login é nativo do browser (pq vc tá usando autenticação básica HTTP) ou é algo específico do seu website?

Comment: @hugomg é nativo do browser.

Comment: Isto é meio gambiarra, mas se quando o usuário fizer o login, tentar logar logo nos dois sites, não é mais fácil silenciar a resposta de erro no caso de ele não ter autorização de logar num site?

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira é isso que estou tentando fazer e não sei como.

Comment: Já tentou inspecionar os headers da requisição no servidor? Você pode alternar a resposta (emitindo um status de erro HTTP como 500) de acordo com isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não controlo a aplicação para a qual vou fazer requisição, então não tenho como manipular os cabeçalhos da resposta :\

Comment: E uma requisição com o método HEAD pra descobrir se está autenticado? Depois não prosseguir se não estiver.

Comment: Vou tentar, valeu :)

Comment: Funcionou essa lance do HEAD?

Comment: @Daniel eu não tenho mais o ambiente para testar =(

Comment: @Daniel no entanto, encontrei uma pergunta semelhante no SO em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545126/ithit-ajax-file-browser-active-directory-webdav-auto-login

Answer (score 4):

Talvez vc possa interceptar a mensagem com o método done jquery ajax, da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://renan/bar/baz",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    // avoid response and use your own behavior
}).error(function (xhr) {
    // Treat the error.
});
```

Comment: Já tô tentando isso =\ ele pede as credenciais antes de executar esses métodos. Se autenticar cai no `done`, senão cai no `fail`.

Answer (score 4):

Já tive problema parecido...

Infelizmente depois de muito tempo perdido a procura de uma solução, cheguei a conclusão que não tinha o que fazer pois - no meu caso - se trata de uma autenticação windows, gerida pelo pool de aplicações.

Eu tinha a opção de mudar todo o mecanismo de login e fazer minhas aplicações gerirem a autenticação - seja por cookie, banco, etc. Mas como o tempo era escasso, resolvi colocar as aplicações no mesmo pool.